# Laravel ::isClassDeviable is not defined

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, laravel-8

I did a composer update and suddenly i found this error.

```
::isClassDeviable is not defined
```

in my composer i have "laravel/framework": "^8.0", then, i installed new packages for laravel-scout and laravel-scout-extended, and run composer update, and was when i got the error, seems like the error comes from inside the HasAttributes itself, im not using any of those methods

im not sure what happend, im posting to see if more people have the same issue and if the problem is deeper than just this method missing.

What i did, is just copy/paste the method from this Laravel Library and now it works.

file src:

```
src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php
```

[Library HasAttributes Docs](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.html#method_isClassDeviable)

[Library HasAttributes Raw File](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php)

Code:

```
protected function isClassDeviable($key)
{
    return $this->isClassCastable($key) &&
        method_exists($castType = $this->parseCasterClass($this->getCasts()[$key]), 'increment') &&
        method_exists($castType, 'decrement');
}
```

Hope this helps someone

Comment: did you import the file before use ?

Comment: what file?  i did an update to composer and it was when it failed

Comment: strange, you say you updated to 8.x and then it was missing some sort of file. Then you copy over a file from the 8.x repo and it works.

Comment: use `HasAttributes` you need to `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes;` like trait you import

Comment: No, sorry, miss understanding, in my composer i have> "laravel/framework": "^8.0", i installed new packages, and run composer update, and was when i got the error, seems like the error comes from inside the HasAttributes itself, im not using any of those methods